# Redo navigation after adding publishing pages

Tags: navigation, site-template

I added some publishing pages after a site was provisioned (using web template, so I am already adding to nav using  in onet.xml).

The pages I am creating are in the navbar of the onet.xml. But they get deleted or something because onet.xml runs first and at that time I don't have publishing pages created (It happens  a little later). Now how do I programatically add these pages to the existing navbar and make sure they go in the right place?

Comment: What type of navigation provider are you using? Is your site template based on a team type site (including blank site)? Publishing Sites tend to use a different navigation provider to 'normal' sites.

Comment: using onet.xml navbar property to generate. I will then need to make sure the pages are in the right section

Comment: I have 2 headers (Mananger and supervisor). the publishing pages need to go under Manager header (in correct sort order). (both manager and supervisor headers are populated with lists and libs. designed in onet.xml)

Comment: Looks like this guy is adding to nav bar but clearing everything. but my issue is I need to use existing navigator and add to header section called "Manager Nav". http://sharepoint2010funfacts.blogspot.com/2011/03/adding-spnavigationnode-to-current.html

Comment: @Moni: I have exact same issue that I can use some help. After provisioning a web I need to use existing nav and make sure the publishing pages are in certain headers. Have you figured it out? I hope someone can help both of us.

Comment: @monica-contera: please add more info to the Q on what you want to achieve exactly (feel free to add screenshots or mock ups). Info should be added to the Q and then in comment remark that you have updated the Q, this way people wont have to scour comments for hints to question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add code from the example you mention [yourself](http://sharepoint2010funfacts.blogspot.com/2011/03/adding-spnavigationnode-to-current.html) to a web scoped features feature receiver, and make sure that the feature is added **after** the feature(s) with the module that provisions the publishing pages, you should be in business.

Features provisioned in ONET is executed synchronously, first by site collection then site scope.

Comment: I guess i will do that. Thank you sir. let me know if you know a good site that good example on nav bar feature.